# How i am supposed to call a mysql database using node.js and exports?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, node-mysql

i am developing an API with node.js, express, etc, using a mysql database. I am using node-mysql to connect and perform queries on my database.

In order to have a clean code, i divided it into controllers and models. But i'm facing this :

models/user.js

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  port     : 3307,
  user     : 'root',
  password : 'root',
  database : 'db'
});

User.prototype.blablabla = function() {
...
connection.query(...);
}
```

models/admin.js

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  port     : 3307,
  user     : 'root',
  password : 'root',
  database : 'db'
});

Admin.prototype.blablabla = function() {
...
connection.query(...);
}
```

The thing is that i have to create a connection to my database on every file, even though i'd like to have only one that i call, and when i'm done, i close it.

But with this configuration, using my controllers who use callbacks and stuff, i cannot close the connection. It is always running.

I'm looking for a secure way to use only one instance of the connection to the database. Is it a good way to do it ? How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

How about you create a specific file for this connection info ?

/connection.js

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  port     : 3307,
  user     : 'root',
  password : 'root',
  database : 'db'
});

module.exports = connection;
```

Because require caches the module it loads, the connection will open only once. ref http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/06/require-and-the-module-system/

Then, note that to close the connection, you can use the connection instance and its method end

```
connection.end();
```

ref https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql

Comment: Ok, thanks man. I'm using express.Router(), do you know how can i connection.open() before each request and then close it after it ?

Comment: The doc says `However, a connection can also be implicitly established by invoking a query:` [ref](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#establishing-connections). To close it after each request, take example on [morgan](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan/blob/master/index.js#L103) and see [this](https://github.com/jshttp/on-finished)

Comment: i don't see why you're giving me theses links